# When testing a method in scalatest, is it possible to mock/stub an object which is instantiated inside the method call?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, scalatest, stubbing

Right now I am writing a testing suite for a method which takes in a string, instantiates a database endpoint, and then queries the endpoint with the string. It then takes this response, performs several transformations to it, and ultimately returns it. It looks roughly like this :

```
method(s: String){
    dbEndpoint database = new dbEndpoint()
    DataFrame df = database.read(s)
    df.transform(...)
}
```

Since I have already written tests for the database endpoint and am confident that it is sufficiently robust, I am only concerned with ensuring that the transformation logic that occurs after the database query is correct. As a result, I want to stub the endpoint such that endpoint.read() returns a small amount of data whose transformation can easily be verified for correctness.

It is my understanding that it is not possible to stub this specific endpoint, since I have no reference to it outside of the scope of the method. Am I wrong? Is there some way that I could go about stubbing/mocking the database from the outside (without changing the method)?

Comment: Don't use the `new` construction method. Instead, add a factory method. You can then inject the factory.

Answer (score 2):

WARNING: This is indeed possible using PowerMock, although it should be done only as last resort as suggested by @bruno-bonanno.

[PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) supports mocking of hardwired local scope dependencies, such as `dbEndpoint`, using the following three facilites:

- `PowerMockito.whenNew`
- `@RunWith`
- `@PrepareForTest`

Here is a working example using Scala, PowerMock, Mockito and JUnit:

```
import org.scalatest.junit.AssertionsForJUnit
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.mockito.Mockito._

class Hardwired {
  def f(i: Int): String = s"I am a real Hardwired instance"
}

class Foo {
  def bar(i: Int): String = {
    val localHardwiredInstance = new Hardwired()
    localHardwiredInstance.f(i)
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[Foo]))
class ExampleSuite extends AssertionsForJUnit {
  @Test def mockLocalHardwiredDependency() {
    val hardwiredMock = mock(classOf[Hardwired])
    when(hardwiredMock.f(3)).thenReturn("I am a mocked Hardwired instance")
    PowerMockito.whenNew(classOf[Hardwired]).withNoArguments().thenReturn(hardwiredMock)
    val foo = new Foo
    assertEquals("I am a mocked Hardwired instance", foo.bar(3))
  }
}
```

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  scalaTest % Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-api-mockito" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-core" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.powermock" % "powermock-module-junit4" % "1.7.4" % Test,
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test,
),
testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-v")
```

I am unsure how to run it with ScalaTest - I believe we need a corresponding `PowerMockRunner`, however currently I was unable to find one.

Comment: Breaking the encapsulation so brutally should be left as a last resort and only if for some reason the code can't be refactored to be more testable... That code also makes the test really hard to read and reason about

Comment: Yes I agree. I do not advise this. The question asked is whether it is possible without changing the method.

Comment: True that, but I'd still write that is not an ideal solution at the beginning of the answer so it doesn't look like is the right thing to do, for him and any other person reading it quickly

Comment: Edited answer now contains a warning.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to modify your code to look like this

```
method(s: String, dbEndpoint database = new dbEndpoint()){
    DataFrame df = database.read(s)
    df.transform(...)
}
```

That way your callers can keep calling the method without caring about knowing about the `dbEndpoint` but on your tests you can create a mock and pass it as the second argument