# How to mock an object (InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName) in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, scalatest

I have some code like this:

```
import java.net.{InetAddress, UnknownHostException}
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.BDDMockito.`given`
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
class XYZ {
  def getAppendedName(prependage: String): String = {
    s"$prependage ${InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName}"
  }
}

@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
class SomeTestSuite extends FunSuite {

  @Mock val inetAddress: InetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost

  @Test
  @throws[UnknownHostException]
  def shouldReturnMocked(): Unit = { //given
    mockStatic(classOf[InetAddress])
    given(InetAddress.getLocalHost).willReturn(inetAddress)
    given(inetAddress.getHostName).willReturn("mocked")
    //when
    val name = (new XYZ).getAppendedName("is")
    //then
    assert(name == "is mocked")
  }
}
```

And ... I have modeled this code after another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768180/when-testing-a-method-in-scalatest-is-it-possible-to-mock-stub-an-object-which), but I cannot seem to get this to run.

I get 2 errors:

There were 2 failures:

```
1) Test mechanism 
java.lang.NullPointerException

and
  2) shouldReturnMocked(com.xyz.abc)
                     org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
                     when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
                     For example:
                         when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
                     
                     Also, this error might show up because:
                     1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
                        Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
                        Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
                     2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

The stacktrace was omitted but points to:
`given(InetAddress.getLocalHost).willReturn(inetAddress)` or
`given(inetAddress.getHostName).willReturn("mocked")` depending on which is first when switching order.

BONUS QUESTION:

I would like to changed the format to be more like what I am familiar with so that the test runs like this:

```
import somestuff
import xxxx.XYZ

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ValidationSuite extends FunSuite {
 
  test("this mock test") {
      // Setup
      val name = (new XYZ).getAppendedName("is")
      assert(name == "is mocked")
  }
}
```

How can I make this aforementioned code work?  I'm also open to use scalatestplus mockito 3.2 solutions, but not open to refactoring my code (which follows the pattern of example above).

NOTE: I have found away around this example, by doing something like:

```
val xyz = new XYZ {

    override def getAppendedName(prependage: String): String = {
    s"$prependage mocked host"
  }
}
```

HOWEVER, the code in my case is called below `getAppendedName` where the method calls other class and object methods that subsequently call `InetAddress`. In these deeper layers, the code should be mocked.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this line?
```@PrepareForTest(Array(classOf[Nothing]))```

Comment: @VladimirKorenev- Thx for point that out. That's a cut n paste error from the example. I'll edit that out.